# Атрибут и свойство объекта. В чем разница?

Tags: значение-слов

Кто может пояснить (или направить в нужном направлении), чем атрибут объекта отличается от свойства объекта? Существуют ли точные определения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибуты – это материально-ощутимые, сопутствующие объекту, элементы, а свойства – его характеристики, абстрактные черты, признаки.  По сути, **атрибут** – **объективное** явление, а **свойство** – **субъективное**. Атрибут - это предмет, знак, а свойство - признак, то есть то, что при знаке, то, что присуще данному знаку. Атрибут  - это предметное сопровождение свойства, его материальное проявление.

Comment: Спасибо. Звучит вполне логично. То есть можно рассматривать атрибут как средство выражения конкретного свойства (или конкретных значений параметров). Допустим, если взять некую абстрактную систему. Определенные значения параметров определяют конкретные свойства объекта и выражаются посредством атрибута (атрибутов).

Comment: Да, это будет верно. Как заметила Алёнка, атрибут - это своего рода проводник свойств.

Answer (score 1):

Атрибут - изменяемое значение конкретно указывающее на объект.
Свойство - значение описывающее объект, но присущее любому колличеству объектов.

Одно свойство может подходить и одному и другому объекту и служит для описания объекта. Атрибут же явный указатель объекта.

Есть люди. Они делятся на взрослых, детей и стариков. На белых, чёрных, жёлтых и так далее.

Так вот "палец", "мозг", это свойства описывающие некий объект.
Только вот палец и мозг есть и у людей и у обезьян.

А если мы скажем "Рука" или "Одежда", это уже будет атрибут. Потому когда мы говорим "Рука", мы имеем ввиду человеческую руку, но не ЛАПУ животного. Ровно как и одежду носят люди, но не носят животные.

Свойство, прошу прощения за тафтологию, может быть свойственно многим объектам, атрибут же - явный селектор. Указатель на объект.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую ответить.

Заглянем в Википедию.

Атрибут — в философии — необходимое, существенное, неотъемлемое свойство предмета или явления (в отличие от преходящих, случайных его состояний).

Так что атрибут – это и есть свойство.

Но в той же Википедии:

Атрибут — в мифологии и иконографии предмет, служащий постоянным устойчивым знаком и отличительным признаком мифологического или реального персонажа или аллегорической персонификации какого-либо понятия (молнии Зевса, весы и повязка Фемиды).

Так что атрибут может быть и предметом, но предмет в религии является символом, проводником к какой-то Сущности, за ним всегда стоит гораздо больше, чем он изображает.

Поэтому (заглянем в dic. academic) «Атрибут подразумевает необходимое отношение к некоторой субстанции, но он сам не может быть субстанцией или существовать без нее».

Comment: Я понимаю, о чём вы говорите, и не собираюсь спорить ни с википедией, ни с авторитетными создателями словарей, но имею и своё мнение, основанное на личном опыте. Например: что является атрибутами царской власти или сотрудника дпс? Корона, скипетр, держава, жезл. У дома есть двери, окна. Чем они являются: атрибутами или свойствами? Свойства сопровождают атрибуты, атрибуты имеют свойства.

Comment: Именно это мне и представляется, когда я думаю об атрибутах...))) Какая-то картина, где кто-то, какой-то монарх, видимо, держит державу - темный шар с крестом. Всего лишь вещь, а сколько за ней стоит, сколько страданий, человеческих судеб, жизней...

Comment: Двери и окна свойствами не являются. Они могут иметь свойство открываться и закрываться и пропускать людей... Так что они тоже проводники какой-то идеи, ее выражения, но не сама идея. И уж никак не свойство.

Comment: Видите, Алёнка, можно и самостоятельно разобраться в сути.